# Permission denied when updating Babun

Tags: linux, shell, cygwin, babun

I tried to update Babun but it say that I do not have the permission to do that. Can anyone help me?

**Babun Update**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using sudo on your command:

```
sudo babun update
```

If that does not work, try doing the same as root:

```
su root babun update
```

**Edit:** Thanks to `Avijit Dasgupta` for the obvious suggestion:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/etc/babun/source/babun-core/tools/update_source.‌‌​​sh
```

**Edit 2:** If everything else fails, you should try to uninstall Babun, reboot the computer and try to install it again (the newest Babun version). You might want to check this FAQs page for Babun uninstal info and other tips: http://babun.github.io/faq.html

Comment: ➜  ~ sudo babun update 
`Executing babun update
cp: cannot open ‘/usr/local/etc/babun/source/babun-core/tools/update_source.sh’ for reading: Permission denied`

Comment: chmod +x /usr/local/etc/babun/source/babun-core/tools/update_source.‌​sh

Comment: I added an alternative command, try that and post the error code (if any) so I can check it tomorrow (PST time).

Comment: I assumed that the file `/usr/local/etc/babun/source/babun-core/tools/update_source.‌​sh` was already executable -- if you're not certain about it then try also  `Avijit Dasgupta` suggestion, it might work.